# Unable to edit the body of a particular answer

Tags: bug, status-completed, editing, editor

I make a large number of edits across Super User every week, but I've not seen this issue before.

If I try to make any edits to [this answer](https://superuser.com/questions/7354/tools-to-keep-my-machine-spick-and-span-windows-xp/7357#7357), the text available for me to edit is trimmed short - only the very first part of the answer is shown, the rest seems to have disappeared.

### Answer as shown originally

[image]

### Answer as shown during editing

[image]

Comment: Very odd. I see the same thing occurring.

Comment: Note - because the question is a "list all your `x`" type question, I closed it as non-constructive. I left it undeleted though so the devs could check it out and figure out what's wrong with editing.

Comment: seems like the cooked HTML is different from source markdown.

Comment: Same here...interesting bug.

Comment: The same thing happens in Opera for me too.  That's peculiar.

Comment: @Sathya Ah, sorry, I didn't see that. Probably a migration issue then.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That post was migrated from Server Fault on July 17, 2009, just a few days after the "migrate to any site" functionality was added (which happend on July 14). The initial version had a bug that caused the migrated post to have the cooked HTML of the migration source's *current* revision, but the Markdown source of the post's *first* revision. This bug was fixed on July 19, but that's of course *after* this particular migration happened. Source control is awesome :)

I have edited the post to contain the final revision of the original Server Fault post, just in case you want to keep the question around (I'll leave that to the Super User moderators).

Comment: Thanks for the follow up, makes perfect sense. :)

Comment: An awesome bug!